# Discord.JS bot is very slow, no idea why

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Sorry for the bad title, I can't think of a good one.

I'm running a self-bot (I know, against TOS but I'm experimenting) and it needs to download any new files (specifically images [gifs too], and videos) when it is sent. It does work but it is very slow and the files that are downloaded are from minutes ago.

Here's my current code:

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
let request = require(`request`);
let fs = require(`fs`);
function download(url, fname){
    request.get(url)
        .on('error', console.error)
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./cmc-memes/"+fname));
}
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});
// lags idk why
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.channel.id === "296056831514509312") {
        console.log(msg.content)
        if(msg.attachments.first()){//checks if an attachment is sent
            download(msg.attachments.first().url, msg.attachments.first().filename);//Function I will show later
        }
    }
});
```

What do I do to fix this?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: 'very slow' - Why do you know that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the specifics of how request.get(url) work (I prefer node-fetch) however if its a synchronous call it would be significantly slowing it down. Otherwise the problem is simply your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found out it starts slow but then catches up, so I'm marking this as answered.